# Conditions where $f'(s)\implies \lim_{t\to s^+}\frac{\|f(t)-f(s)\|}{t-s}=\|f'(s)\|$ holds?

Tags: analysis, limits

Let $f:[a,b]\to E$ differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $E$ a normed vector space, and $s\in(a,b)$. Then it is stated that

$$\lim_{t\to s^+}\frac{\|f(t)-f(s)\|}{t-s}=\|f'(s)\|\tag{1}$$

I assumed that the reason to the above equality is because $E$ is a $\Bbb K$-vector space where $\Bbb R\subseteq \Bbb K$ (for some field $\Bbb K$), then

$$\lim_{t\to s^+}\frac{\|f(t)-f(s)\|}{t-s}=\lim_{t\to s^+}\left\|\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}\right\|=\left\|\lim_{t\to s^+}\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}\right\|=\|f'(s)\|$$

because a norm is a continuous function and $t-s=|t-s|$ is an scalar on $E$. Then I have two questions here:

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. Suppose that $\Bbb R\not\subseteq \Bbb K$, then I suppose that (1) doesnt not necessarily holds, right?

Comment: The way you've written it down on the left hand sides the sign of $t-s$ is not defined. Therefore the first equality sign in the second equation is not correct.

Comment: @Thomas oh, I see, I forget to complete the question... I will edit. Fixed.

Comment: I'm having some problem with your terminology. Probably a translation issue. When you write "$\mathbb{R}$ is the field (or a subfield) of $E$", you don't mean that $\mathbb{R}\subset E$ (which would be part of $\mathbb{R}$ being a subfield of $E$), you mean that $\mathbb{R}$ is the scalar field, or a subfield of the scalar field, of $E$, i.e. $E$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space (a $K$-vector space inherits an $L$-vector space structure for all subfields $L$ of $K$), right?

Comment: Yes @DanielFischer, exactly, Im saying that is required that $\Bbb R$ is a field of the normed vector space $E$, not a subset of $E$, that $E$ is a $\Bbb K$-vector space where $\Bbb R\subseteq\Bbb K$.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. And if $E$ isn't an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, then $f'(s)$ probably already doesn't make sense. We could define differentiability for maps between (nice subsets of) $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, or generally $K$-vector spaces where $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, and it might happen that an interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a set for which it makes sense to speak of the differentiability of maps $[a,b]\to E$. But in context, it is safe to assume that $E$ is a real or complex vector space.

Comment: Every definition of "normed vector space" that I know of requires $E $ to be a vector space over $\Bbb {R} $ or $\Bbb {C} $, so you are good to go.

Comment: @PhoemueX What a coincidence in timing. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063245/normed-vector-space-and-absolute-value) on that topic was just asked.