# Normed vector space and absolute value

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, normed-spaces, absolute-value

When I look to the [Norm article of Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)), it seems that a norm is defined on a vector space over a subfield of the complex. In France, while this is usually the case, the definition of a vector space is a bit more general, and a vector space can be over a field endowed with an [Absolute value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_(algebra)).

Is there a name in English for those "Normed vector spaces"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article you cite is written from the perspective of an analyst, so it takes a narrow interpretation of a norm. A search for "normed linear/abstract space" together with "absolute value" or "valued field" shows that this term is also used for linear spaces over fields other than subfields of $\mathbb C$. Here is [one example](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mattiasj/731/exer/nvspaces1.pdf) and here is [another](https://books.google.com/books?id=RdB6U3EtZM0C&lpg=PA271&ots=BuWoLFgS5M&dq=vector%20space%20over%20a%20general%20field%20absolute%20value&pg=PA271#v=onepage&q&f=false), with a screenshot of the relevant part:

> [image: over a field]

Comment: For information about normed spaces over arbitrary fields and some introductory references see:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2568042/113061